# Problem with value of SIngleton in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton

Hi have a problem with singleton Class in iPhone app.
I have create a simple class for visualization of NSString value.
My problem is generate when i try to stamp a NSString in a textVIew.
I call my methods and the value of string in Singleton class is (invalid) (i have tested it with debug).
Can you help me with the code solution.

my code:

```
#import "UntitledViewController.h"
#import "SingletonController.h"

@implementation UntitledViewController

@synthesize resetTextEvent;
@synthesize buttonSavePosition;


-(IBAction)stamp{

    textEvent.text = [sharedController name];

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sharedController =  [SingletonController sharedSingletonController];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end




#import "SingletonController.h"


@implementation SingletonController

@synthesize name;

static SingletonController *sharedController = nil;

+(SingletonController*)sharedSingletonController{

    if(sharedController == nil){
        sharedController = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        }

    return sharedController;
}


+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[self sharedSingletonController] retain];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;
}

- (id)retain
{
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount
{
    return NSUIntegerMax;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release
{
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease
{
    return self;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];
        }
    return self;
}


-(void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];
```

is problematic. `name` refers to an instance variable, not your property. So what's happening is your string is being assigned to `name`, but it's an autoreleased object. So, at some point in the future, `name` is released automatically and refers to deallocated memory.

If you've specified the `name` property as either `retain` or `copy`, then either of the following lines will property retain the object:

```
self.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"];
name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"] retain];
```